# Silly question regarding probability?

Tags: probability, statistics, conditional-expectation, bayes-theorem

A probability exercise which I believe that it is written in slightly dodgy manner as I have trouble finding a solution for it. The way I go about the solution is to have the problem split into three expected values - {(5,3)-default, (6,2), (4,4)}, but I have no idea how to finish it. Could it be that I am going totaly wrong about it?

Here is the exrcise I have:
[image]

Comment: I agree, the exercise is a little dodgy.  In particular, exactly what does it mean to draw a cake at random?  Does it mean picking one of the two boxes at random (and then taking a cake from that box), or does it mean picking one of the eight cakes at random?

Comment: If I had to choose, I would say that they meant that you chose a cake, not a box. Meaning the assistant draws a banana cake with $3/8$ chance. But it's not super clear. If this is an assignment, you should talk to an instructor for clarification.

Comment: I've bad bad luck with these coffee shops today, but I'm going to go with "random box" rather than "random cake".  It's hard to sort out a natural mechanism to select a cake randomly and we're dealing with a clerk who can't even keep the two boxes straight.

Comment: This is a past exam paper I am dealing with now :(

Comment: Your professor has an unfortunate affection for A. coffee shops and B. imprecisely worded questions.

Comment: This is the way he shows affection towards his pupils - torture them with nonsensical exercises. I have an exam tomorrow and the questions there have a chance to be worded even worse....

Comment: As the comments reflect, there are really only two ideas for what might be meant here.  Can you work the problem in both cases?

Comment: I think you are supposed to take a cake from the whole lot of 8 cakes and then have one of the 8 cakes as an unknown type from the two sets and then work the way from here and I am not sure what to do with it...

Comment: I'll post something below (meant to cover both cases).  I recommend checking it...something about your coffee shop problems causes me to make errors.  Glad I am not taking your test.

Comment: @lulu, I'm in the "random box" camp myself.  I have an easier time picturing the poor clerk randomly picking a box from under the counter; the alternative is to picture them opening *both* boxes and going "eeny meeny miny moe..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, it is not clear what it means to select a cake at random.  There are two competing ideas:

A.  ("Random Cake") Choose a cake at random (so probability $\frac 58$ of chocolate and probability $\frac 38$ of banana).

B. ("Random Box")  Choose one of the two boxes at random (so probability $\frac 12$ of either chocolate or banana).

Not hard to do both cases simultaneously

Let's go over what happened with the annoying first customer.

Case I.  The cake was a chocolate cake. (prob = $\frac 58$ or $\frac 12$).

Ia.  It is returned to the chocolate box (prob = $\frac 12$)

Ib.  It is placed in the banana box (prob= $\frac 12$)

Case II.  The cake was a banana cake. (prob = $\frac 38$ or $\frac 12$).

IIa.  It is returned to the banana box (prob = $\frac 12$)

IIb.  It is placed in the chocolate box (prob= $\frac 12$)

The reasonable customer now arrives.  the only scenario in which they might get a banana cake is IIb (which we are in with probability $\frac 38\times \frac 12$ or $\frac 12\times \frac 12$ ).  If we are in that case, the chocolate box contains the five real chocolate cakes and the one imposter, so there is just a $\frac 16$ probability of a mistake.  Putting it all together we get $$\frac 38\times \frac 12\times \frac 16=\frac 3{96}\;\;or\;\;\frac 12\times \frac 12\times \frac 16=\frac 1{24}$$.

Comment: This is beautiful!!! The way I started doing it was just drawing a mind map with some state machine like diagram. http://i.imgur.com/P8t3TOI.jpg

Comment: On the picture was the way I started doing it but I think I did it slightly wrong...

Comment: Not quite following your picture...but what I wrote makes sense?

Comment: Yes it does answer it! Thank you again!!! :)

Comment: No problem.  Good luck on your test!

Answer (score 0):

The experiment has three stages:

1. Pick a cake at random
2. Return the cake to a randomly chosen box
3. Pick a cake at random from the chocolate box

It's unclear whether in stage (1) the box is chosen at random, or the cake is chosen at random, but you can proceed under either assumption.

There's only one combination of events where the second customer gets a banana cake: In stage (1) a banana cake is selected (prob either $\frac12$ or $\frac38$); *and* in stage (2) the banana cake gets returned to the chocolate box (prob $\frac12$ assuming independence from the stage 1 event); *and* in stage (3) that selfsame banana cake is selected for the second customer (prob $\frac16$ conditional on the previous stage 1 and stage 2 events). Now multiply the probabilities at the individual stages to get the requested probability.